# Any other preprocessor directives in VBScript/Classic ASP?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, preprocessor

The only pre-process directive that I know about in VBScript / Classic ASP is the #include. I don't know if that is the official name but I'm basically looking for code that can execute code or other instructions *before* the general VBScript.

Are there any other such directives in VBScript? Such as #If or something?

I'd like to be able to conditionally include or exclude a certain include file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are six directives.  They are:

- ## include
- ## config
- ## echo
- ## fsize
- ## flastmod
- ## exec

Comment: The aspemporium.com is written in ASP.NET itself so it looks like they've moved on too!  But it's nice they keep the old stuff around.

Answer (score 3):

According to MSDN, though [others are valid for Server Side Include files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525185.aspx) - only `#include` works in ASP.